# i am trying to unload data from snowflake internal stage to unix file path using COPY INTO and GET command, but getting error

Tags: python, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-connector

I am running all the sql scripts under the scripts path in a for loop and copying the data into @priya_stage area in snowflake and then using GET command , i am unloading data from stage area to my Unix path in csv format. But I am getting error.
**Note**: this same code works on my MAC but not on unix server.

```
    import logging
    import os
    import snowflake.connector
    from snowflake.connector import DictCursor as dict
    from os import walk
    
    try:
        conn = snowflake.connector.connect(
            account = 'xxx' ,
            user = 'xxx' ,
            password = 'xxx' ,
            database = 'xxx' ,
            schema = 'xxx' ,
            warehouse = 'xxx' ,
            role = 'xxx' ,
        )
    
        conn.cursor().execute('USE WAREHOUSE xxx')
        conn.cursor().execute('USE DATABASE xxx')
        conn.cursor().execute('USE SCHEMA xxx')
    
        take = []
        scripts = '/xxx/apps/xxx/xxx/scripts/snow/scripts/'
        os.chdir('/xxx/apps/xxx/xxx/scripts/snow/scripts/')
    
        for root , dirs , files in walk(scripts):
            for file in files:
                inbound = file[0:-4]
                sql = open(file , 'r').read()
                # file_number = 0
                # file_number += 1
                file_prefix = 'bridg_' + inbound
                file_name = file_prefix
                result_query = conn.cursor(dict).execute(sql)
                query_id = result_query.sfqid
                sql_copy_into = f'''
                copy into @priya_stage/{file_name}
                from (SELECT * FROM TABLE(RESULT_SCAN('{query_id}')))
                DETAILED_OUTPUT = TRUE
                HEADER = TRUE
                SINGLE = FALSE
                OVERWRITE = TRUE
                max_file_size=4900000000'''
                rs_copy_into = conn.cursor(dict).execute(sql_copy_into)
    
                for row_copy in rs_copy_into:
                    file_name_in_stage = row_copy["FILE_NAME"]
                    sql_get_to_local = f"""
                      GET @priya_stage/{file_name_in_stage} file:///xxx/apps/xxx/xxx/inbound/zip_files/{inbound}/"""
                    rs_get_to_local = conn.cursor(dict).execute(sql_get_to_local)
    except snowflake.connector.errors.ProgrammingError as e:
        print('Error {0} ({1}): {2} ({3})'.format(e.errno , e.sqlstate , e.msg , e.sfqid))
    finally:
        conn.cursor().close()
        conn.close()
```

Error

```sh
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Generic_local.py", line 52, in <module>
  rs_get_to_local = conn.cursor(dict).execute(sql_get_to_local)
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/snowflake/connector/cursor.py", line 
  746, in execute
  sf_file_transfer_agent.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site- 
  packages/snowflake/connector/file_transfer_agent.py", line 379, in execute
  self._transfer_accelerate_config()
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site- 
  packages/snowflake/connector/file_transfer_agent.py", line 671, in 
  _transfer_accelerate_config
  self._use_accelerate_endpoint = client.transfer_accelerate_config()
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site- 
  packages/snowflake/connector/s3_storage_client.py", line 572, in 
  transfer_accelerate_config
  url=url, verb="GET", retry_id=retry_id, query_parts=dict(query_parts)
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site- 
  packages/snowflake/connector/s3_storage_client.py", line 353, in _. 
  send_request_with_authentication_and_retry
  verb, generate_authenticated_url_and_args_v4, retry_id
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site- 
  packages/snowflake/connector/storage_client.py", line 313, in 
  _send_request_with_retry
  f"{verb} with url {url} failed for exceeding maximum retries."
  snowflake.connector.errors.RequestExceedMaxRetryError: GET with url b'https://xxx- 
  xxxxx-xxx-x-customer-stage.xx.amazonaws.com/https://xxx-xxxxx-xxx-x-customer- 
  stage.xx.amazonaws.com/?accelerate' failed for exceeding maximum retries.
```

**This link redirects me to a error message .
https://xxx-
xxxxx-xxx-x-customer-stage.xx.amazonaws.com/https://xxx-xxxxx-xxx-x-customer-
stage.xx.amazonaws.com/?accelerate**

**Access Denied error :**

```
<Error>
<Code>AccessDenied</Code>
<Message>Access Denied</Message>
<RequestId>1X1Z8G0BTX8BAHXK</RequestId>
<HostId>QqdCqaSK7ogAEq3sNWaQVZVXUGaqZnPv78FiflvVzkF6nSYXTSKu3iSiYlUOU0ka+0IMzErwGC4=</HostId>
</Error>
```

Comment: Does your Unix server reaches Snowflake via a Proxy? Or is there any kind of network filtering in between? The URL **sfc- prod2-ds1-3-customer-stage.s3.amazonaws.com** is the internal stage URL of the Snowflake account, but you might be having some network filtering in between.

Comment: First and foremost run curl -vvv <SF URL> from the Unix host and see if it is getting resolved correctly or not. Run the same from MAC as well and this will give the difference if the former test is failing. Most likely from the error it seems to be a network action that is blocking the access to SF.

Comment: I strongly recommend you review your query history to see what actual SQL Snowflake is receiving for that GET command that is failing, my guess is the SQL is malformed and you'll need to edit your code to accommodate.

Comment: What's the error now?

Comment: @Sergiu yes there was a firewall issue that was blocking internal stage location, that got resolved  . I am extracting data from 18 tables in snowflake by creating a stage for each table . but my code fails with after extracting for 5 tables.                                                              `packages/snowflake/connector/file_transfer_agent.py", line 772, in result "errno": ER_FAILED_TO_DOWNLOAD_FROM_STAGE,snowflake.connector.errors.OperationalError: 253002: GET with url b'https://.amazonaws.com/xxx/stages/xxx/xxx.csv.gz' failed for exceeding maximum retries`

Comment: That is still an access issue to the internal stage, the Python connector is trying to download a file and doesn't have access to it. You should check again with your network team the the URL mentioned is allowed.